# GET Trello JSON to put in a string var

Tags: javascript, json, trello

I'm trying to get the JSON that a TRELLO API Url returns and put it into a string.  On my own private board I am getting "401 Unauthorized".  But the Trello Api doesn't seem to give any way to authorize a user through the URL.  If I try a public board I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.trello.com/1/board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c?key=68d02bf40d2ad57dd9eb418eb15f9564. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

This is my code:

```
     <body>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>

      <script>

      var list = $.getJSON(" https://api.trello.com/1/board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c? key=68d02bf40d2ad57dd9eb418eb15f9564");
      document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = list;


      </script>
      <div id="print">
      </div>
      </body>
```

Comment: Cross domain ajax call is not supported on most modern browsers. You may do it on server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) call which is allowed to be cross-domain.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.trello.com/1/board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c?&callback=?", {
    key: '68d02bf40d2ad57dd9eb418eb15f9564'
})
.success(function(responseObj) {
    document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(responseObj);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/yLGTQ/)**

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

Comment: was it supposed to be $.getJSON() or $.getJSONP()??

Comment: `$.getJSON`, exactly as I wrote.

Comment: sweet worked like a charm ...now hopefully I can get to my private board the same way.